# How to store the username in the URL while working on Ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to front-end and was trying to create a Login page which had username and password to login. I wanted to store the Logged-In username in the URL, so had to use the PUT method in the AJAX call. But my login is always failing as I am unable to pass the correct username attribute in the URL, Please see the below code to refer:

Again how to pass the {username} in the URL, you can see the below URL in ajax call where I have this username attribute.

jQuery:

```
$("#login-user").validate({

        submitHandler: userLogin

    });

    function userLogin() {
        var data = $("#login-user").serialize();


        if (userName != '' && password != '')
        {
            $.ajax({

                url: 'http://www.website.com/database/tableusers/{username}/login',
                type: 'PUT', 
                data: data,

                success: function(data) {
                    if (data == 0) {

                        result.html('<span class="error">Incorrect username or password</span>')

                    } else if (data == 1) {

                        window.location = "tothepage.html";

                    } else {

                        $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function() {

                            $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; ' + data + ' !</div>');

                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Comment: where did you define `username`? It's undefined

Comment: using a GET method to send a username to the server IS A BAD PRACTICE. even if you are using HTTPS, the user name is still transparent and may lead to security breaks. why not using POST to send the username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined either `userName` or `password`. `data` is correct, though.

Also, it might be right for your backend code, but you probably would have to use `POST` (`type`).

So, you're missing this:

```
function userLogin() {
    var data = $("#login-user").serialize();

    var userName=$("#userNameInputID").val();
    var password=$("#passwordInputID").val();

    if (userName != '' && password != '')
    {
        $.ajax({

            url: 'http://www.website.com/database/tableusers/'+userName+'/login', //just concatenate userName here (case sensitive)
            type: 'PUT', 
            data: data,
....
```

Comment: data variable is not valid right, since it is not storing anything in your case. How to resolve that @Gabriel

Comment: had to add 
var data = $('#user').val() + ' ' + $('#pass').val(); and it worked like a charm

Comment: Assuming that `#login-user` is your form and your fields are named, `$("#login-user").serialize()` will create an object `{fieldName:fieldValue, ...}` wich will be sent to the server (since it's assigned to the `data` property in your ajax call).

Comment: Yeah Gabriel, I just reverted the data to store var data = $("#login-user").serialize();

Answer (score 0):

Keep the username as a variable.

```
var url = 'http://www.website.com/database/tableusers/'+username+'/login';
```

Answer (score 0):

Build the URL first and store it in a variable, then use the variable in the AJAX call.

For instance:

```
 var userUrl = 'http://www.website.com/database/tableusers/' + userName + '/login';

 $.ajax({

                url: userUrl,
                type: 'PUT', 
                data: data,

                success: function(data) {
```

Comment: Why should he build the url first?

Comment: Hey @Jason, thank you so much. How to store the variable username before that instead of var data = $("#login-user").serialize();

Answer (score 0):

You just need to access the `username` and `password` variables from your `data` object and define them as `var`s

```
function userLogin() {
    var data = $("#login-user").serialize();
    var username = data.username;
    var password = data.password;

    if (username != '' && password != '')
    ...
```

Also, you can inject the variable for `username` into the URL  by adding it with the `+` string operator

```
url: 'http://www.website.com/database/tableusers/' + username + '/login';
```